# NTP Synchronization issue & it turned off automatically

Tags: 14.04, server, sync, ntp

Due to Time Synchronization Issue, We manually tried to sync the time by,

sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org

It works. But instead of running this command everytime maually, I setup `NTP` by installing

`sudo apt-get install ntp`

The output of `timedatectl` gives :

```
    Local time: Mon 2017-01-09 10:19:24 CET
  Universal time: Mon 2017-01-09 09:19:24 UTC
        Timezone: Europe/Paris (CET, +0100)
     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: no
 Last DST change: DST ended at
                  Sun 2016-10-30 02:59:59 CEST
                  Sun 2016-10-30 02:00:00 CET
 Next DST change: DST begins (the clock jumps one hour forward) at
                  Sun 2017-03-26 01:59:59 CET
                  Sun 2017-03-26 03:00:00 CEST
```

NTP enabled & NTP Synchronized value is `yes` now. But, if i try this command tommorrow,
it gives NTP Synchronized value to `No` & time is still behind 20 minutes that causes wrong time issue.

**EDIT :**

`sudo service ntp status` gives Starting NTP server ntpd

ntpq -p gives,

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 dedibox.demonge 195.83.222.27    2 u   10   64    1    4.715   -4.367   0.000
 electra.pinklem 129.69.1.153     2 u    9   64    1    8.588   -5.518   0.000
 head1.mirror.ca 195.66.241.10    2 u    8   64    1    5.990   -5.512   0.000
 lon.jonesey.net 81.174.136.35    2 u    7   64    1    5.191   -4.197   0.000
 x.ns.gin.ntt.ne 249.224.99.213   2 u    6   64    1   24.962   -3.461   0.000
 alphyn.canonica 132.246.11.231   2 u    5   64    1   75.727   -4.524   0.000
```

Comment: Is you `ntpd` running? Check with `service ntp status` and add the output of `ntpq -p` to your question.

Comment: @Thomas added the output. Can you check now?

Comment: This looks good. Your ` ntpd` is running and can also connect to the ntp servers. Check the same when the problem occurs. If the `ntpd` is not running, search your logfiles for the reason. If `ntpd` is still running, check if it can reach the ntp servers ( `nptq -p` ) and search the logfiles.

Comment: By this time tomorrow, for `sudo service ntp status` command, it shows NTP is not running. That's the issue. It gets automatically stopped.

Comment: Have a look at `/var/log/syslog`to see if there are error messages from ntpd (or maybe some other file in /var/log). If your local time when starting differs from the 'real' time more than 1000s (default), ntpd will not synchronise; you can override this behaviour by adding option `-g` to the start of ntpd by setting `NTPD_OPTS='-g'` in `/etc/default/ntp`, see `man ntpd`.

Comment: @ridgy `NTPD_OPTS='-g'` is already exists in that file.

Comment: @ridgy there are more logs. How i know its ntp error?

Comment: In terminal issue `grep ntpd /var/log/syslog`; or, if this does not give you results, `grep -R ntpd /var/log/*`.  Messages coming from `ntpd` should always contain the name `ntpd`in the log file.

Comment: @ridgy No Error.

Comment: Does `No Error` mean there is no message at all? If there are messages containing `ntpd`, please add them to your question.